# How to run code daily, weekly, monthly in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I have an api end point where users hit with amount in data payload. I need to track users amount on daily weekly and monthly basis. I am using express.session to track user activity.

daily, weekly, monthly amount needs to be zero for all requests at start of the day, week, month respectively. as per information I got I might need to run a cron job for doing so...

```js
suppose I have a user whose information in session cookie as follows
var req.session.ipCookie = {
  dailyAmount: 50,
  weeklyAmount: 150,
  monthlyAmount: 250
}


const amount = 25
if (req.session.ipCookie) {
  req.session.ipCookie.dailyAmount = req.session.ipCookie.dailyAmount + Amount;
  req.session.ipCookie.weeklyAmount = req.session.ipCookie.weeklyAmount + Amount;
  req.session.ipCookie.monthlyAmount = req.session.ipCookie.monthlyAmount + Amount;
}
```

I like to make dailyAmount, weeklyAmount, monthlyAmount set to 0
 if it is new day or new day of week and month.

How can I check if req is in new week, month or a day and make respective amount to zero.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do what you want to do is to create a CRON job on your server which will run you nodejs file when tou want. [Look at this tutorial](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215767047-Creating-a-custom-Cron-Job)